# Get json data based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem with getting the specific data based on my id. 
This is my main html.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <button id="btn">Button</button>
    <br>
    <div id="id01"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my main js

```
 var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "url.../incident";
contentType="applicaton/json; charset=utf-8";
method="GET";
dataType= "json";

ourRequest.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this.responseText);
}
}
ourRequest.open("GET", url, true);
ourRequest.send();
});
function myFunction(response) {
var arr = JSON.parse(response);
var out = "<table>";

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += "<tr><td>" + 
    arr[i].Address +
    "</td><td><a href='lista.html?id="+arr[i].ID+"'>" +
    arr[i].ID +
    "</a></td><td>" +
    arr[i].Category +
    "</td></tr>";
}
out += "</table>";
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

This will show me only three data.

this is my lista.html

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="id02">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is my js for my lista.html.

```
 var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "url../incident?id=";
 contentType="applicaton/json; charset=utf-8";
 method="GET";
 dataType= "json";

 ourRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   myFunction(this.responseText);
  }
 }

 ourRequest.open("GET", url, true);
 ourRequest.send();
 function myFunction(response)
 {
  var arr = JSON.parse(response);
  var out = "<table>";
  out +="<tr><td>" + 
  arr.Address +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.CaseID +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.Category +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.Date +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.Description +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.ID +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.InputDate +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.Latitude +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.Longitude +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.ReportedBy +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.Subcategory +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr.Time +
    "</td></tr>"
  out += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("id02").innerHTML = out;
 }
```

So when I click on that arr[i].ID it should send me to th lista.html with the specific ID and specific data.
For example if i click on ID=1, the url look like lista.html?id=1, but nothing shows.

Comment: Please, for a better understanding add the important html code to your question.

Comment: @reporter I just have an <div id="id02">
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the id to the request url if the api you send request to expects that

```
var url = "url?id={your id here}"
```

Comment: I have different IDs. Each ID has an list of items, which contains address, caseid...

Answer (score 0):

In your table you have to use arr.Address instead of response.Address, since the arr is the parsed json object.

You can use console.log to see if the data you need is really there:

```
function myFunction(response) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(arr);
}
```

You don't need to read the location href with jQuery, since you already know the id of the request you sent!

Comment: No, I have a lot of IDs. But when I want to call a specific ID, I want to show a table with these data: address, CaseID,

Comment: And if you call that specific id, the response is also for that specific id, so why can't you fill the table with that response?

Comment: I have no idea. I mean, I try to call the url with different IDs, but nothing happens. I don't even get errors.

Comment: If you call the url straight in the address bar of your browser (http://myurl/?id=myid), does the browser show a result? If not, then the problem is on the server. If this returns the desired result, then check the answer by @reporter.

Comment: If you can't call the url at all, then the server simply does not return anything. If you are calling an external API you have to check the documentation. If you wrote the server code yourself, you have to return / echo something as a response, after the server process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

So My mistake was like this instead of :

```
var url = "url../incident?id=";
```

I should have written :

```
var url = "url../incident?id="+getQueryVariable("id");
```

And write this function in the end of my js for my lista.html

```
   function getQueryVariable(variable)
   {
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
   }
```